# Change has_many to has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a `Invoice` model that `has_many` `Transactions`. I need to change the relationship from `has_many` to `has_and_belongs_to_many` without losing my current data so that I can associate a single transaction (payment) with multiple invoices.

My current model structure:

```
class Invoice
    has_many :transactions

end


class Transaction
    belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Comment: Are you certain you want to use HABTM instead of `has_many :through`?

Comment: @jvillian It's pretty much the same thing right? Except the join table is a model I'd create? I've got several other models using this structure and it works well.

Comment: Welp. I suppose if you *might* what to store data on the association object at some point in the future, you can save yourself another data migration but using `has_many :through`. Personally, I never use HABTM, but that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a ton of HABTM associations built in the last few years. Usually people go ahead and specify the entire association graph:

```
class Invoice
  has_many :invoice_transactions
  has_many :transactions, through: :invoice_transactions
end

class InvoiceTransaction
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :transaction
end

class Transaction
  has_many :invoice_transactions
  has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_transactions
end

# in a migration
create_table :invoice_transactions do |t|
  t.belongs_to :invoice
  t.belongs_to :transaction
end
execute('INSERT INTO invoice_transactions VALUES (invoice_id, transaction_id) FROM (SELECT id, transaction_id FROM invoices)')
```

This is because InvoiceTransaction is likely to gain some additional behavior, but that's a (very little bit of) speculative programming (and probably worth doing).

What you're asking for exactly can be accomplished with:

```
class Transaction
  has_any_belongs_to_many :invoices
end

class Invoice
  has_and_belongs_to_many :transactions
end
```

This is described further (along with another sample migration) in the [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Comment: Well stated. I believe, however, the OP's question is about migrating existing data (*I need to change the relationship from has_many to has_and_belongs_to_many without losing my current data*).

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge how would I save data to the `InvoiceTransaction` model? Say I wanted to save the amount for a given invoice there.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the right place to put it (`amount` sounds like a property of the Transaction), but you'd just add an `amount` column in your migration.